# スプレッドシートのプルダウンについて

Tags: google-spreadsheet

「食物選択」というシートと「食物リスト」というシートの2つがあるファイルを使っています。
「食物選択」のA列には「フルーツ」「野菜」などのストリングが入っています。そしてB列には「黄色」「オレンジ」「赤」などのストリングが入っています。C列をプルダウンにし、そのプルダウンの候補は、「食物リスト」を参照したいです。
「食物リスト」のA列には同じく「フルーツ」「野菜」などのストリングが入っており、B列にも「黄色」「オレンジ」「赤」などのストリングが入っています。C列にはA列とB列に当てはまる食材がすでにリストとして入っており、例えば「フルーツ」「黄色」がA列・B列にある行は、例えばパイナップル、マンゴーなどがあります。
このパイナップルやマンゴーなど、A列とB列が「食物選択」シートと「食物リスト」とで一致したC列の情報を、「食物選択」のC列のプルダウン候補として表示させる方法を教えてください。

Comment: 文字の説明だけでは分かりにくいのでサンプル画像を追加いただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

データの入力規則で食物選択のC列のプルダウンメニューにしたい箇所を選択、プルダウン（範囲内）で食物リストのA列とB列を選択、A列の項目とB列の項目で色を変えてやって完了です。